# New gas range setting off smoke/gas detectors

Tags: gas, exhaust-fan, oven, range

I converted our kitchen's range to gas. The gas line was installed professionally but I connected the new stove. As part of setup I heated the oven to 350 to test the burners. Soon after reaching temperature the house alarms went off. I think that it was monoxide not smoke. I was running the exterior vent but it isn't above stove.

Is this normal for a new oven, should I run a self-clean? Do the oven burners need to be adjusted? Do I need an exhaust hood (I've had houses with gas ranges but never a hood, and we rarely use the exhaust fan but it seems like everyone has hoods now)?

Comment: Is there a suitable inlet for fresh air? My understanding is that carbon monoxide forms when there isn't enough oxygen. Extracting air isn't sufficient, there needs to be a vent to let air in too.

Comment: Are you using natural gas or propane, and are the orfices the correct size. More information needed

Comment: Natural gas. The range manual says it is factory configured for NG and I didn't use the LP conversion kit.

Comment: @Carl There weren't windows open, but it is a drafty house. The kitchen is small but it has two open doors.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, you really need an externally vented hood. Sorry, but gas stoves put out both carbon dioxide and even worse, some amounts of carbon monoxide, which is much worse.  While it may not be an enormous risk, it's still important enough to vent combustion gases from a gas range to the outside. Really!  All you have to do to kill yourself is forget to turn off a burner or oven and go to sleep and not wake up again.   Sorry, dude, but you need an externally vented hood.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've lived in many houses and apartments with gas ovens without hoods. And I would rarely use the kitchen fans. Have I just had beter ventilated kitchens?

Comment: I agree with your answer about killing yourself in your sleep, however, one must also remember to _turn on_ the vent. Having it is useless if it's not on! `</stating the obvious>`

Answer (score 0):

Something must be seriously messed-up for a nat gas oven or burner to produce carbon monoxide.  I have started three brand new ovens over the years and never had detectors go off. Also never depended on exhaust vents ; when I burn something on the range or in the oven ,it requires several minutes to get the detector to turn off. I would look for a foreign material like plastic packing of some sort that burned. You do not need to see smoke to cause the detectors to go off. I have no idea how you convert a range to gas; what kind of range was it? A new oven or range (cook top) should not need adjustment in my experience.

Comment: By 'convert' I mean added a gas line and replaced the electric range with a new gas range.

Comment: I may have over-stated the risk, but I just don't like allowing combustion gasses to remain in my home. Maybe belt and suspenders but that's just me!